# Issues while translating a static method to kotlin from java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to understand and translate a java code to kotlin. The code is  available [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/tree/master/usbSerialExamples/src/main/java/src/com/hoho/android/usbserial/examples).

Basically there are two class files

1. `DeviceListActivity`   :   *Allows user to select an `item` from a ListView*
2. `SerialConsoleActivity`  :  *Performs read/write operation on the selected `item`*

The relevant code section from `DeviceListActivity` is follows:

```
private void showConsoleActivity(UsbSerialPort port) {
        SerialConsoleActivity.show(this, port);
    }
```

relevant code snip from `SerialConsoleActivity` is follows:

```
public class SerialConsoleActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = SerialConsoleActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Driver instance, passed in statically via
     * {@link #show(Context, UsbSerialPort)}.
     *
     * <p/>
     * This is a devious hack; it'd be cleaner to re-create the driver using
     * arguments passed in with the {@link #startActivity(Intent)} intent. We
     * can get away with it because both activities will run in the same
     * process, and this is a simple demo.
     */

    private static UsbSerialPort sPort = null;

    ...
    //more code
    ...


   static void show(Context context, UsbSerialPort port) {
        sPort = port;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, SerialConsoleActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

The part I am not able to understand is **how is the static method `show` from `SerialConsoleActivity` able to retain the `port` object being passed?** There isn't an instance of the parent class involved (which is also the whole purpose of static method).

To achieve a similar effect as above I wrote following code, but it doesn't work:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var sPort :UsbSerialPort?=null
    private val GET_AVAILABLE_USB_DEVICE = 1

    companion object {
        const val PORT = "port"
        fun show(context: Context, port: UsbSerialPort) {
            sPort = port
        }
    }
```

sPort is not accessible from inside the show.

If I move the `show` function outside the companion object,

Then I cannot do the following

```
MainActivity.show(this, port_obj)
```

The "devious hack" warning in the original post suggests to *recreate the driver* by passing arguments, but alas, it is [not clear how would one create an port object from arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297216).

Another option is to implement a serializable object (because port is not yet serializable) and pass it via the intent but I'm not yet versed with serializing. Thus, I am looking for a similar work-around as done in the original work in "kotlin'y way". Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to port you old  static `sPort` you need to add it to your companion, companion object is a replacement for static methods and properties as well.

```
companion object {
    const val PORT = "port"
    UsbSerialPort sPort = null;
    fun show(context: Context, port: UsbSerialPort) {
        sPort = port
    }
}
```

Comment: How about creating the `intent` and starting the parent activity? Is it okay to put it inside the `show` method?

Comment: You do the same to launch your intent, nothing changes here